# Spark, SQL aggregation based on a second data set

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have two datasets (dataframes)

1. idPeersDS -  which has an id column and it's peers' ids.
2. infoDS - which has two type columns (type1, type2) and a metric column.

--

```
idPeersDS
+---+---------+
| id|    peers|
+---+---------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|
|  2|[2, 1, 6]|
|  3|[3, 1, 2]|
|  4|[4, 5, 6]|
|  5|[5, 4, 6]|
|  6|[6, 1, 2]|
+---+---------+


infoDS
+---+-----+-----+------+
| id|type1|type2|metric|
+---+-----+-----+------+
|  1|    A|    X|  10.0|
|  1|    A|    Y|  20.0|
|  1|    B|    X|  30.0|
|  1|    B|    Y|  40.0|
|  2|    A|    Y|  10.0|
|  2|    B|    X|  20.0|
|  2|    B|    Y|  30.0|
|  3|    A|    X|  40.0|
|  4|    B|    Y|  10.0|
|  5|    A|    X|  20.0|
|  5|    B|    X|  30.0|
|  6|    A|    Y|  40.0|
|  6|    B|    Y|  10.0|
+---+-----+-----+------+
```

I need to calculate the zscore of the metric for each id grouped by type1 and type2. But it is not the score of the metrics for the grouped data, it is zscore of the metrics of peers with in a group. If a peerId doesnot have a metric in the group, the peerId's metric is treated as 0.

example:
for group ("A", "X") and for id = 1, the peers are (1,2,3), the metrics for zscore will be (10, 0, 40); since id = 2 doesn't exist in group ("A","X") it is 0. id=5 is not a peer of id=1 so it is not part of zscore calculation.

```
+---+------+---------+-----------+
| id|metric|    peers|type1|type2|
+---+------+---------+-----------+
|  1|  10.0|[1, 2, 3]|    A|    X|
|  3|  40.0|[3, 1, 2]|    A|    X|
|  5|  20.0|[5, 4, 6]|    A|    X|
Z = (X - μ) / σ
Z = (10 - 16.66666) / 16.99673

Z = -0.39223

 Output should be the following table. I can compute zscore if `peersmetrics` column instead of `zScoreValue` column like my code did.
    +---+------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
    | id|metric|    peers|zScoreValue|type1|type2|    peersmetrics
    +---+------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
    |  1|  10.0|[1, 2, 3]|      -0.39|    A|    X|    [10, 0, 40]
    |  3|  40.0|[3, 1, 2]|       1.37|    A|    X|    [40, 10, 0]
    |  5|  20.0|[5, 4, 6]|       1.41|    A|    X|    [20, 0 , 0]
    |  1|  40.0|[1, 2, 3]|       0.98|    B|    Y|    [40, 30, 0]
    |  2|  30.0|[2, 1, 6]|       0.27|    B|    Y|    [30, 40, 10]
    |  4|  10.0|[4, 5, 6]|       0.71|    B|    Y|
    |  6|  10.0|[6, 1, 2]|      -1.34|    B|    Y|
    |  1|  30.0|[1, 2, 3]|       1.07|    B|    X|
    |  2|  20.0|[2, 1, 6]|       0.27|    B|    X|
    |  5|  30.0|[5, 4, 6]|       1.41|    B|    X|
    |  1|  20.0|[1, 2, 3]|       1.22|    A|    Y|
    |  2|  10.0|[2, 1, 6]|      -1.07|    A|    Y|
    |  6|  40.0|[6, 1, 2]|       1.34|    A|    Y|
    +---+------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

Edit1: SQL solution is equally appreciated. I can transform SQL to Scala code in my spark job.

Following is my solution but the computation is taking longer than I wish.
the size of true datasets:
idPeersDS has 17000 and infoDS  has 17000 * 6 * 15

Any other solution is greatly appreciated. Feel free to edit/recommend title and correct grammar. English is not my first language. Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
val idPeersDS = Seq(
  (1, Seq(1,2,3)),
  (2, Seq(2,1,6)),
  (3, Seq(3,1,2)),
  (4, Seq(4,5,6)),
  (5, Seq(5,4,6)),
  (6, Seq(6,1,2))
).toDS.select($"_1" as "id", $"_2" as "peers")

val infoDS = Seq(
  (1, "A", "X", 10),
  (1, "A", "Y", 20),
  (1, "B", "X", 30),
  (1, "B", "Y", 40),
  (2, "A", "Y", 10),
  (2, "B", "X", 20),
  (2, "B", "Y", 30),
  (3, "A", "X", 40),
  (4, "B", "Y", 10),
  (5, "A", "X", 20),
  (5, "B", "X", 30),
  (6, "A", "Y", 40),
  (6, "B", "Y", 10)
).toDS.select($"_1" as "id", $"_2" as "type1", $"_3" as "type2", $"_4" cast "double" as "metric")




def calculateZScoreGivenPeers(idMetricDS: DataFrame, irPeersDS: DataFrame, roundTo: Int = 2)
(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {

  import spark.implicits._

  // for every id in the idMetricDS, get the peers and their metric for zscore, calculate zscore
  val fir = idMetricDS.join(irPeersDS, "id")
  val fsMapBroadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(
    idMetricDS.toDF.map((r: Row) => {r.getInt(0) -> r.getDouble(1)}).rdd.collectAsMap)
  val fsMap = fsMapBroadcast.value
  val funUdf = udf((currId: Int, xs: WrappedArray[Int]) => {
    val zScoreMetrics: Array[Double] = xs.toArray.map(x => fsMap.getOrElse(x, 0.0))
    val ds = new DescriptiveStatistics(zScoreMetrics)
    val mean = ds.getMean()
    val sd = Math.sqrt(ds.getPopulationVariance())
    val zScore = if (sd == 0.0) {0.0} else {(fsMap.getOrElse(currId, 0.0)- mean) / sd}
    zScore
  })

  val idStatsWithZscoreDS =
    fir.withColumn("zScoreValue", round(funUdf(fir("id"), fir("peers")), roundTo))
  fsMapBroadcast.unpersist
  fsMapBroadcast.destroy
  return idStatsWithZscoreDS

}

val typesComb = infoDS.select("type1", "type2").dropDuplicates.collect

val zScoreDS = typesComb.map(
  ept => {
    val et = ept.getString(0)
    val pt = ept.getString(1)
    val idMetricDS = infoDS.where($"type1" === lit(et) && $"type2" === lit(pt)).select($"id", $"metric")
    val zScoreDS = calculateZScoreGivenPeers(idMetricDS, idPeersDS)(spark)
    zScoreDS.select($"id", $"metric", $"peers", $"zScoreValue").withColumn("type1", lit(et)).withColumn("type2", lit(pt))
  }
).reduce(_.union(_))


scala> idPeersDS.show(100)
+---+---------+
| id|    peers|
+---+---------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|
|  2|[2, 1, 6]|
|  3|[3, 1, 2]|
|  4|[4, 5, 6]|
|  5|[5, 4, 6]|
|  6|[6, 1, 2]|
+---+---------+


scala> infoDS.show(100)
+---+-----+-----+------+
| id|type1|type2|metric|
+---+-----+-----+------+
|  1|    A|    X|  10.0|
|  1|    A|    Y|  20.0|
|  1|    B|    X|  30.0|
|  1|    B|    Y|  40.0|
|  2|    A|    Y|  10.0|
|  2|    B|    X|  20.0|
|  2|    B|    Y|  30.0|
|  3|    A|    X|  40.0|
|  4|    B|    Y|  10.0|
|  5|    A|    X|  20.0|
|  5|    B|    X|  30.0|
|  6|    A|    Y|  40.0|
|  6|    B|    Y|  10.0|
+---+-----+-----+------+


scala> typesComb
res3: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([A,X], [B,Y], [B,X], [A,Y])

scala> zScoreDS.show(100)
+---+------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| id|metric|    peers|zScoreValue|type1|type2|
+---+------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
|  1|  10.0|[1, 2, 3]|      -0.39|    A|    X|
|  3|  40.0|[3, 1, 2]|       1.37|    A|    X|
|  5|  20.0|[5, 4, 6]|       1.41|    A|    X|
|  1|  40.0|[1, 2, 3]|       0.98|    B|    Y|
|  2|  30.0|[2, 1, 6]|       0.27|    B|    Y|
|  4|  10.0|[4, 5, 6]|       0.71|    B|    Y|
|  6|  10.0|[6, 1, 2]|      -1.34|    B|    Y|
|  1|  30.0|[1, 2, 3]|       1.07|    B|    X|
|  2|  20.0|[2, 1, 6]|       0.27|    B|    X|
|  5|  30.0|[5, 4, 6]|       1.41|    B|    X|
|  1|  20.0|[1, 2, 3]|       1.22|    A|    Y|
|  2|  10.0|[2, 1, 6]|      -1.07|    A|    Y|
|  6|  40.0|[6, 1, 2]|       1.34|    A|    Y|
+---+------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Here is my answer. This solution did run significantly faster (< 1/10th) than my previous solution I have in the question on my true datasets.
I avoided collect to driver and map and union of datasets in the reduce.

```
val idPeersDS = Seq(
  (1, Seq(1,2,3)),
  (2, Seq(2,1,6)),
  (3, Seq(3,1,2)),
  (4, Seq(4,5,6)),
  (5, Seq(5,4,6)),
  (6, Seq(6,1,2))
).toDS.select($"_1" as "id", $"_2" as "peers")

val infoDS = Seq(
  (1, "A", "X", 10),
  (1, "A", "Y", 20),
  (1, "B", "X", 30),
  (1, "B", "Y", 40),
  (2, "A", "Y", 10),
  (2, "B", "X", 20),
  (2, "B", "Y", 30),
  (3, "A", "X", 40),
  (4, "B", "Y", 10),
  (5, "A", "X", 20),
  (5, "B", "X", 30),
  (6, "A", "Y", 40),
  (6, "B", "Y", 10)
).toDS.select($"_1" as "id", $"_2" as "type1", $"_3" as "type2", $"_4" cast "double" as "metric")


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

idPeersDS: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, peers: array<int>]
infoDS: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, type1: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> idPeersDS.show
+---+---------+
| id|    peers|
+---+---------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|
|  2|[2, 1, 6]|
|  3|[3, 1, 2]|
|  4|[4, 5, 6]|
|  5|[5, 4, 6]|
|  6|[6, 1, 2]|
+---+---------+


scala> infoDS.show
+---+-----+-----+------+
| id|type1|type2|metric|
+---+-----+-----+------+
|  1|    A|    X|  10.0|
|  1|    A|    Y|  20.0|
|  1|    B|    X|  30.0|
|  1|    B|    Y|  40.0|
|  2|    A|    Y|  10.0|
|  2|    B|    X|  20.0|
|  2|    B|    Y|  30.0|
|  3|    A|    X|  40.0|
|  4|    B|    Y|  10.0|
|  5|    A|    X|  20.0|
|  5|    B|    X|  30.0|
|  6|    A|    Y|  40.0|
|  6|    B|    Y|  10.0|
+---+-----+-----+------+


scala> val infowithpeers = infoDS.join(idPeersDS, "id")
infowithpeers: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, type1: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> infowithpeers.show
+---+-----+-----+------+---------+
| id|type1|type2|metric|    peers|
+---+-----+-----+------+---------+
|  1|    A|    X|  10.0|[1, 2, 3]|
|  1|    A|    Y|  20.0|[1, 2, 3]|
|  1|    B|    X|  30.0|[1, 2, 3]|
|  1|    B|    Y|  40.0|[1, 2, 3]|
|  2|    A|    Y|  10.0|[2, 1, 6]|
|  2|    B|    X|  20.0|[2, 1, 6]|
|  2|    B|    Y|  30.0|[2, 1, 6]|
|  3|    A|    X|  40.0|[3, 1, 2]|
|  4|    B|    Y|  10.0|[4, 5, 6]|
|  5|    A|    X|  20.0|[5, 4, 6]|
|  5|    B|    X|  30.0|[5, 4, 6]|
|  6|    A|    Y|  40.0|[6, 1, 2]|
|  6|    B|    Y|  10.0|[6, 1, 2]|
+---+-----+-----+------+---------+


scala> val joinMap = udf { values: Seq[Map[Int,Double]] => values.flatten.toMap }
joinMap: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,MapType(IntegerType,DoubleType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(MapType(IntegerType,DoubleType,false),true))))

scala> val zScoreCal = udf { (metric: Double, zScoreMetrics: WrappedArray[Double]) =>
    |   val ds = new DescriptiveStatistics(zScoreMetrics.toArray)
    |   val mean = ds.getMean()
    |   val sd = Math.sqrt(ds.getPopulationVariance())
    |   val zScore = if (sd == 0.0) {0.0} else {(metric - mean) / sd}
    |   zScore
    | }
zScoreCal: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,DoubleType,Some(List(DoubleType, ArrayType(DoubleType,false))))

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


val infowithpeersidmetric = infowithpeers.withColumn("idmetric", map($"id",$"metric"))
val idsingrpdf = infowithpeersidmetric.groupBy("type1","type2").agg(joinMap(collect_list(map($"id", $"metric"))) as "idsingrp")

val metricsMap = udf { (peers: Seq[Int], values: Map[Int,Double]) => {
    peers.map(p => values.getOrElse(p,0.0))
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

infowithpeersidmetric: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, type1: string ... 4 more fields]
idsingrpdf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [type1: string, type2: string ... 1 more field]
metricsMap: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,ArrayType(DoubleType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(IntegerType,false), MapType(IntegerType,DoubleType,false))))

scala> val infoWithMap = infowithpeers.join(idsingrpdf, Seq("type1","type2")).withColumn("zScoreMetrics", metricsMap($"peers", $"idsingrp")).withColumn("zscore", round(zScoreCal($"metric",$"zScoreMetrics"),2))
infoWithMap: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [type1: string, type2: string ... 6 more fields]

scala> infoWithMap.show
+-----+-----+---+------+---------+--------------------+------------------+------+
|type1|type2| id|metric|    peers|            idsingrp|     zScoreMetrics|zscore|
+-----+-----+---+------+---------+--------------------+------------------+------+
|    A|    X|  1|  10.0|[1, 2, 3]|[3 -> 40.0, 5 -> ...| [10.0, 0.0, 40.0]| -0.39|
|    A|    Y|  1|  20.0|[1, 2, 3]|[2 -> 10.0, 6 -> ...| [20.0, 10.0, 0.0]|  1.22|
|    B|    X|  1|  30.0|[1, 2, 3]|[1 -> 30.0, 2 -> ...| [30.0, 20.0, 0.0]|  1.07|
|    B|    Y|  1|  40.0|[1, 2, 3]|[4 -> 10.0, 1 -> ...| [40.0, 30.0, 0.0]|  0.98|
|    A|    Y|  2|  10.0|[2, 1, 6]|[2 -> 10.0, 6 -> ...|[10.0, 20.0, 40.0]| -1.07|
|    B|    X|  2|  20.0|[2, 1, 6]|[1 -> 30.0, 2 -> ...| [20.0, 30.0, 0.0]|  0.27|
|    B|    Y|  2|  30.0|[2, 1, 6]|[4 -> 10.0, 1 -> ...|[30.0, 40.0, 10.0]|  0.27|
|    A|    X|  3|  40.0|[3, 1, 2]|[3 -> 40.0, 5 -> ...| [40.0, 10.0, 0.0]|  1.37|
|    B|    Y|  4|  10.0|[4, 5, 6]|[4 -> 10.0, 1 -> ...| [10.0, 0.0, 10.0]|  0.71|
|    A|    X|  5|  20.0|[5, 4, 6]|[3 -> 40.0, 5 -> ...|  [20.0, 0.0, 0.0]|  1.41|
|    B|    X|  5|  30.0|[5, 4, 6]|[1 -> 30.0, 2 -> ...|  [30.0, 0.0, 0.0]|  1.41|
|    A|    Y|  6|  40.0|[6, 1, 2]|[2 -> 10.0, 6 -> ...|[40.0, 20.0, 10.0]|  1.34|
|    B|    Y|  6|  10.0|[6, 1, 2]|[4 -> 10.0, 1 -> ...|[10.0, 40.0, 30.0]| -1.34|
+-----+-----+---+------+---------+--------------------+------------------+------+
```